# How to convert SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES query to LINQ C#?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to execute a select top 1 with ties, but I'm getting trouble to do so.

I need all the last records of orderdetails, some orders can have more than one article in the list.

```
var qry = (from ordd in db.OrderDetails
           join ord in db.Orders on ordd.OrderId equals ord.OrderId
           join cust in db.Salespersons on ord.SalespersonId equals cust.SalespersonId
           join comp in db.Companies on ord.CompanyId equals comp.CompanyId
           join pro in db.Products on ordd.ProductId equals pro.ProductId                              
           where (ord.OrderId == ordd.OrderId && pro.ProductId == ordd.ProductId)
           orderby ordd.OrderId descending
           select new { ordd })
           .Distinct()
           .ToList();

           foreach (var item in qry)
           {
               dt.Rows.Add(item.ordd.Reference, 
                           item.ordd.Quantity,
                           item.ordd.Description, 
                           item.ordd.Price, 
                           item.ordd.Price * item.ordd.Quantity);
           }
```

Comment: May we have a [mcve]. For a simple list like {1,2,3,4,1,2,5,5,5}. What will be your expected result for top 1 descending? {5,5,5} or {5} or 5? For the first option you can simply groupy by instead of distinct.

Comment: For example, I have a table of order details this one can have N articles with the same orderid I need all that articles but only the last ones that the user has generated. in descending order, using your example must be {5,5,5} 5 = orderid

Comment: What issue are you having with your code? Can you explain what you mean by "WITH TIES"?

Comment: I have the next query for bringing all the latest records with the same orderid, but I'm getting trouble for translating it to C# LINQ, please any idea could be grateful 
`SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM orderdetails 
ORDER BY orderid DESC;`

Comment: @AnthonyOvalles, Ho sorry I didn't understand that you where talking about [SQL keyword `[ WITH TIES ] `](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Basically replace your Distinct/Top1 by a GroupBy

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more generic answer, with a custom object it will be easier to explain.
GroupBy on the field you want order on. This way all the row with the same orderID will be together.
Order Desc on this key, and the first group will be all the row with the max orderID

```
var input = new Foo[] {
    new Foo{GroupId=1,Label="a" },
    new Foo{GroupId=2,Label="b" },
    new Foo{GroupId=3,Label="c" },
    new Foo{GroupId=3,Label="d" },
    new Foo{GroupId=2,Label="e" },
    new Foo{GroupId=4,Label="Bar" },
    new Foo{GroupId=4,Label="Bar" }
};

var result = input.Where(x => x.Label!="Bar")         //-> { a, b, c, d, e }
                    .GroupBy(x => x.GroupId)          //-> {1: a} {2: b, e} {3: c, d}
                    .OrderByDescending(x=> x.Key)     //-> {3: c, d} {2: b, e} {1: a} 
                    .First();
```